# Get rid of "You don't have permission to run the emulator" in VS2012/WP8 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator, admin-rights

I'm starting to write WinPhone apps in my VS 2012 Pro with Windows Phone 8 SDK installed properly. When I hit F5 to launch a project in the phone emulator, VS tries to launch the WP emulator, but I get the message "You don't have permission to run the emulator" from "Windows Phone Emulator".

The message box also contains the checkbox "Join the Hyper-V Administrators security group" which is checked by default. If I press the Retry button, the UAC warning appears as expected, and the WinPhone emulator is starting. But this annoying message appears again and again after closing the emulator. Sure I leave it opened for debugging, I mean every new session of work at the pc.

Yes, the message doesn't appear if I launch VS with admin rights, but that's not a normal process.  I'd like to get rid of this message when I launch VS as usual with non-elevated privileges. Is it possible at all? If so, then what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried manually adding your user account to the Hyper-V Administrators group, logging out, and then logging back in?

Comment: @mikekol, I needed to sign out to make it work - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding myself to the Hyper-V Administrators group manually did not work - until I read the message under the "Join the Hyper-V Administrators security group" checkbox. When I signed out and logged in again, the problem was solved.

But I wonder why this action isn't performed automatically even if we leave the checkbox ticked...

Comment: How can I join "Join the Hyper-V Administrators security group" in Windows8.1 Enterprise?