# Windows Phone Emulator Error Message

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation

When I start the emulator ,the program shows this error message:

> You don't have permission to run the emulator.

Then I click retry and the program gives me another error message like the following picture:
[image]
  What is the problem?

Comment: I think the popup is pretty clear about what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

from here: [Get rid of "You don't have permission to run the emulator" in VS2012/WP8 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572661/get-rid-of-you-dont-have-permission-to-run-the-emulator-in-vs2012-wp8-sdk)

"Adding myself to the Hyper-V Administrators group manually did not work - until I read the message under the "Join the Hyper-V Administrators security group" checkbox. When I signed out and logged in again, the problem was solved."