# Unable to run windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I am running visual studio 2013 with windows 8.1 pro , I have enabled hyper-v from bios and enable it from program and features also. Firstly when I run my project it gives message like this

[image: image 1]

after that when I clicked retry it gives this deployment error

[image: image 2]

Need help in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Try running visual studio 2013 as an administrator this sometimes helps fix the permission issue running the emulator the first time.

Answer (score 0):

After checking in that textbox where you have to add your lap to the Hyper-V Administrators, just try restarting the machine. 
Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572661/get-rid-of-you-dont-have-permission-to-run-the-emulator-in-vs2012-wp8-sdk)

You should try out these too

1.Run VS 2012 as administrator.

2.Open Hyper-V Manager and check the Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch from Virtual Switch Manager. Remove the emulator switch and start a new instance of the emulator.

3.If your host computer has a WLAN connection, you should check whether it is running fine or not.

4.If your host computer is in a dedicated network, you can do a wired tethering and create a peer to peer network with another computer. Enable unrestricted internet in one of the systems, share the connection with the other computer, the emulator running in that, will also get the shared internet.