# You don't have permission to run the emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am facing problem in deploying windows phone 8 app in the emulator. But each time I am going to deploy its showing the message like the figure. Can any one please help me how can I get rid off this disgusting message? I am using using VS Express 2012 with update for in Windows 8.1 Pro.
[image: The following image shows the problem]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get rid of "You don't have permission to run the emulator" in VS2012/WP8 SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572661/get-rid-of-you-dont-have-permission-to-run-the-emulator-in-vs2012-wp8-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hit the Retry button.  If that succeeds then log off of the machine and then logon again.

Comment: Log off from which machine? My Computer or the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing retry will add you to the Hyper-V administrator security group. After this you have to sign out of your development machine and then log in again for changes to take effect , and then deploy app to the Emulator.